# Difference between full text and free text search in solr (other search db)

Tags: solr, full-text-search

New to search databases and working with one. What is the difference between full text and free text search/index?

Comment: Unless you have a more specific case, you can safely assume that they're synonyms.

Comment: Are there any performance differences?

Comment: Since they refer to the same thing and mean the same thing, that question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

**They are kind of same. More precisely they are just synonyms.**

They are techniques used by search engines to find results in a database.
Solr uses Lucene project for it's search engine. It is used when you have a large documents to be searched and, you can't use LIKE queries with normal RDMS considering the performance.

Mianly it's follows two stages indexing and searching. The indexing stage will scan the text of all the documents and build a list of search terms. In the search stage, when performing a specific query, only the index is referenced, rather than the text of the original documents.

Suppose you typed John and Ryan, query will return will all the items in document which either contains "John" or "Ryan". Order and case sensitiveness doesn't matter.

In nutshell, unless you are using/terming them in specific use case, they are just calling different name for same person.

*Call him Cristiano or CR7, they are same :)*